# MIPS $gp register

Tags: mips

Is there a danger in using the `$gp` register to store a value? I guess my question is what is the true functionality of `$gp` and is it invoked behind-the-scenes somehow so that if I were to use it, things could go very very wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, $gp register points to the global area. [Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Compiler_register_usage) indicates that you should store it when you write a function (see .cprestore).

If you need to use it (honestly, cant see why), remeber these things:

> 1)Always store it in the Saved
>   Register Area of your stack.
>
> 2)Always load that value into the $gp
>   when destroying the stack.
>
> 3) Dont use it. (i.e dont  access
>   global scope)

Also, i'm not sure, but you can forget about PIC code.